# Regex Find Segment of Document then use sub regex

Tags: regex

Given a set like the following:

```
START:ITEM
SUBTAG:Value
OTHERSUBTAG:SUBTAG:Value
NAME:CaptureMe
END:ITEM

START:ITEM
MISCSTUFF:SUBTAG:Value
OTHERMISC:SUBTAG:Value
SOMETAG:SUBTAG:Value
NAME:IgnoreMe
ENDINGTAGS:
END:ITEM
```

How would I use regex to find each collection, and only match if it contains a specific "NAME" value?

To clarify, there can be any number of sub tags between the "START" and "END" tag.

This is the regex I'm working with right now, but the issue is if it doesn't match it's "START" "END" pair, it will just move to the next and select.

```
START:TITLE\n(?!NAME)(.|\n|)*?(?:NAME:\s*(?!IgnoreMe).*)(.|\n|)*?END:TITLE
```

How do I make it fail to match if it doesn't find the correct title immediately.

Comment: What is `TITLE`?

Comment: a repeating capturing group will only capture the last match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex should be something like this:

```
(?s)START:ITEM\b((?:(?!START:ITEM).)*?\bNAME:(CaptureMe|IgnoreMeNot).*?)END:ITEM
```

Explanation:

```
(?s)
START:ITEM\b
(?:
  ((?!START:ITEM).)*?             # negative lookahead:
                                  # read lazily characters while there is no START:ITEM ahead
  \bNAME:(CaptureMe|IgnoreMeNot)  # capture only names CaptureMe and IgnoreMeNot
  .*?                             # read lazily characters until you get to the END:ITEM
)
END:ITEM
```

Take a look at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ytI12n/8)

Comment: If there is a line finishing by `NAME` (such as `FIRSTNAME`), you won't capture the wrong one: https://regex101.com/r/ytI12n/6

Answer (score -1):

This simple one should do the trick

```
(?s)START:ITEM.*NAME:CaptureMe.*?END:ITEM
```

As you are looking for all the blocks with a specific NAME value, in this case, NAME:CaptureMe

For the modifiers you can use, like (?s) please refer to [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

Also, .*? means anything anytime, lazily. Once it finds the next required block, it'll stop.

Comment: I honestly want to know why this answer was downvoted without reason...